# TransactionScope: How do I Read back the results of a committed transaction?

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I want to do work in a distributed transaction, commit it, then be able to read the results. Something like:

```
using( var ts = new TransactionScope() )
{
do work on connection A
do work on connection B

ts.Complete();
}

read back work on A
read back work on B
```

This doesn't work consistently because the TransactionScope ends as soon as all the resources have said they will commit (start of phase 2), not that they have committed (end of phase 2) and the commits happen on a different thread.

Is there some way to force the commit to be synchronous? Or some other pattern I should be using to read back the results?

Comment: The back end is Oracle (via latest ODP.NET) and MSMQ

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would expect this to work, since you should be blocked until it is committed (or rolled back). Are you perhaps using lock-avoiding mechanisms (nolock etc)? You could always do the reads in another Serializable transaction (i.e. a second `TransactionScope`) - that should ensure the reads are true.

Comment: I tried the a second TransactionScope and I had the same issues.

Comment: @remack - that is surprising; that kinda makes the transaction non-transactional...

Comment: It looks like it is due to Oracle transaction semantics. See here: [Oracle link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm#i17856).  In particular table 13-2 and the paragraph just below it on referential integrity-- you can't make the second (reading) transaction wait on the write commits on the first transaction.